# Issues implementing Google Maps in RoR even with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, iframe

I have tried all day to get this to work.

HTML Version that works perfectly

```
<style type="text/css">
    #map-container {
        padding: 6px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
        box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
        width: 90%;
    }

    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

</style>

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.loadmax.com/files/Hotload.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(42.8777416,-97.3809789);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
            var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.origin_lng,
                    dataPhoto.origin_lat);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div></div>
```

When i try to implement this into a rails project:

either by adding it all into an html.erb file or breaking it up and putting everything where it should go.

I have even tried using iframe and still can not get this implemented into a rails application

```
<iframe src="url/to/map.html"></iframe>
```

is there something that i am missing... i know that the html page works perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Gmaps using [Gmaps4rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/gmaps4rails)

1: Add it to your Gemfile

```
gem 'gmaps4rails'
```

2: Define a variable in your **controller**:

```
@map_loc = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(User.all) do |user, marker|
  marker.lat user.coordinates.last
  marker.lng user.coordinates.first
end
```

3: In the view:

```
map{:style=>'height: 300px;'}
= javascript_include_tag "//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"
= javascript_include_tag "//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"
- content_for :scripts do
:javascript
$(function(){
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {maxZoom: 17}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(#{@map_loc.to_json});
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
});
```